# Python function to merge unique values form multiple lists to one list

Tags: python, list, function, merge

I am pretty new to Python. I am trying to write a function that will merge unique values in separate lists into one list.  I keep getting a result of a tuple of lists.  Ultimately I would like to have one list of unique values from my three lists -a,b,c.  Can anyone give me a hand with this?

```
def merge(*lists):
    newlist = lists[:]
    for x in lists:
        if x not in newlist:
            newlist.extend(x)
    return newlist

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,5,6]
c = [5,6,7,8]

print(merge(a,b,c))
```

I am getting a Tuple of Lists

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: For order-preserving output, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68626841/).

Answer (score 23):

You may just need sets:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [3,4,5,6]
>>> c = [5,6,7,8]
>>>
>>> uniques = set( a + b + c )
>>> uniques
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about them being in the original order, the easiest and likely fasted way is to use set functions:

```
>>> set().union(a, b, c)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

If you *do* care about the original order (sets happen to preserve it in this case, but aren't guaranteed to), then you can fix your original attempt by realising that the argument `lists` contains a tuple of all of the original lists you passed in. This means that iterating over it gets you each of those lists one at a time, rather than the elements in them - you can fix this by using the itertools module:

```
for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists):
   if x not in newlist:
      newlist.append(x)
```

Also, you would want `newlist` to start out as an empty list rather than a copy of the input lists.

Comment: +1 for using union instead of adding the lists together beforehand. This means that you can use other iterables instead of just lists.

Comment: Note that depending on the number of unique values the time to check `x not in newlist` will grow for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

**Handling a Dynamically Generated List of Lists**

A common use case is generating a list of lists dynamically, with each child list sometimes having an arbitrary length:

```
import random
abc, values = [], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for i in range(3):
    l = []
    for j in range(3):
        l.append(values[random.randint(0, len(values) - 1)])
    abc.append(l)
```

If you're working with a list of lists, simply summing them as proposed by g.d.d.c. doesn't work. That is:

```
uniques = set( a + b + c )
```

The hiccup comes from the fact that you have to specifically reference the lists `a`, `b`, and `c`. The answer by Ivc is really nice and gets us closer:

```
set().union(a, b, c)
```

But again, you have to explicitly reference your lists.

**The Solution**

To get the unique values from a list of lists with arbitrary lengths, you can use [positional expansion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
import random
abc, values = [], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for i in range(3):
    l = []
    for j in range(3):
        l.append(values[random.randint(0, len(values) - 1)])
    abc.append(l)
# The Important Line Below
unique = set().union(*abc)
print(unique)
```

Which will return the appropriate values unordered (e.g. `["d", "b", "a", "d"]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge(*lists):
    newlist = []
    for i in lists:
            newlist.extend(i)
    return newlist

merge_list = merge(a,b,c,d)

merge_list = set(merge_list)

merge_list = list(merge_list)

print(merge_list)
```